# How to give Iframe mouse when focus when mouseover?

Tags: html, iframe, focus, mousewheel

I have an iframe and I would like to use the mousewheel to zoom in and out of the iframe content, but currently my main page is scrolling at the same time the iframe content is.

I want to allow my main page to have mouse wheel focus when the mouse is not over the map, but let the map (iframe) have focus when the mouse is hovering it:

http://digitouchmedia.com/digiMaps.html

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need access to the iframe's window object.  This is only allowable if your iframe obeys the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Provided that you are on the same origin, [you can access the IFrame window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.frames):

```
window.frames['nameOfYourIFrame'].focus();
```

To do this when you mouse over the iframe, I would consider nesting the iframe in a DIV element that has a body big enough to provide a "border" that can be used for detecting mouse enter and mouse exit.  Attach the focus code above to this event handler.

NOTE: if the browser window is not active and in focus, I don't believe mouse events will occur.  I could be mistaken.

Comment: unfortunately, I do not have access to the content within the iframe window. it is linked to an outside domain